# Couldn't use the whereNotExists clause correctly in Laravel 8 Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, where-clause

I have 2 tables, one with different users, and the second table is an invoice table called "factures" and has a foreign key of userid, I called it client_id, which I am trying to get is the number of clients created_by a certain administrator and who have no invoices yet, here is what I tried:

```
$clients = User::select('id')
            ->where([['created_by',$membre_id],['role','Client']])
            ->orWhere([['updated_by',$membre_id],['role','Client']])
            ->whereNotExists(function($query)
              {
                  $query->select(DB::raw('client_id'))
                        ->from('factures')
                        ->where('created_by',$member_id);

              })->get();
```

but this query gives me all clients created_by $member_id without exception.
What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the following:

```
$clients = User::select('id')
    ->where(function($query) use($member_id){
        $query->where([['created_by',$membre_id],['role','Client']])
            ->orWhere([['updated_by',$membre_id],['role','Client']])
    })
    ->whereNotExists(function($query) use($member_id){
        $query->select(DB::raw('client_id'))
            ->from('factures')
            ->where('created_by',$member_id);
    })
    ->get();
}
```

This answer applied the `OR` condition only between the first two conditions (created_by and updated_by) and its result is `AND` with the third condition.

Comment: it's giving me the following error :Undefined variable: membre_id, for some reason it can't recognize my parametre passed with the function :     public function clientsSansFacture($membre_id){....}

Comment: still unrecognisable :/: Undefined variable: member_id

Comment: Now check again. `$member_id` needed to be used in both closure functions

Comment: thanks for your time it worked

Comment: What have you changed from the original code? Why did the original code not work? Add some explanation to your answer to make it helpful.